# html mailto - insert body in mail from variable

Tags: javascript, html, html-email, mailto

I'm using `mailto:` protocol on my page (html). I have textarea field where user can write some text, now I want to include that text in body of email.

Any sugestions how to change the code, that the function will work as I wish?

My current code (contact-message:

```
    <form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post">
            <p class="contact-name">
                <input id="contact_name" type="text" placeholder="Name" value="" name="name" />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-email">
                <input id="contact_email" type="text" placeholder="Email Addresse" value="" name="email" />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-message">
                <textarea id="contact_message" placeholder="Nachricht" name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p class="contact-submit">

                <a class="submit" href="mailto:mail@adress.com?subject=Mail request&body=contact-message">Send mail</a>

            </p>

            <div id="response">

            </div>
     </form>
```

Comment: You want do that: if user click on submit buttom then email will be send?

Comment: @Ionut AJAX? Are you serious?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, yeah, I mean AJAX. Combined with PHP of course.

Comment: OP doesn't need that. OP is asking for the `mailto:` protocol, not for how to send an email with php + ajax. The answer below is correct (even the unmeritory downvote)

Comment: @Ionut what does ajax/php have to do with using `mailto:` href?

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript as

```
function sendMail()
{
    var body = document.getElementById("contact_message").value;
    window.location.href = "mailto:mail@example.org?subject=Mail request&body="+body;
}
```

Call function as

```
<a class="submit" onclick="sendMail()">Send mail</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function MyFunction(){
  var email = document.getElementById("input").value;
  window.location.href = "mailto:" + email + "?subject=Test email&body=Testing email";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="input"/>
    <button onclick="MyFunction()">Click</button>
  </body>
</html>
```